# Linear combinations of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Tell me whether I am right. Is it a linear combination when  I have this type of reduced row form?

[image: my effort] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu1nR.jpg))

Comment: Very hard to understand what is written there, even with the large version. I think it would be better for you to type the question.

Comment: If i have the last row is all zero and the augmented one is constant so is not a  linear combination right ?

Comment: Unless the constant itself is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to check if the column vectors are linearly independent from each other, using Gaussian Elimination to put it in Reduced Row Echelon Form. So, the vectors appear to be linearly independent judging from the leading 1's.